# Cant getting a link to a widget component UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have an actor with class HexCell and I added a widget component with class HexWidget to him, then I try to get a link to the widget component, but nothing works. I tried many solutions but nothing works. How get reference on widget class?

```
class BATTLETECH_API UHexWidget : public UUserWidget
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

};





class BATTLETECH_API AHexCell : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AHexCell();

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category="Grid Setup")
    UHexWidget* Widget;


protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;



};

void AHexCell::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    1 // the code compiles without errors, but the engine crushed if start
    Widget = Cast<UHexWidget>(GetOwner()->FindComponentByClass(UHexWidget::StaticClass()));

    2 // the code compiles without errors and the scene starts, but the link remains empty
    Widget = Cast<UHexWidget>(this->FindComponentByClass(UHexWidget::StaticClass()));

    3 //note: see reference to function template instantiation 'T *AActor::FindComponentByClass<UHexWidget>(void) const' being compiled
    Widget = GetOwner()->FindComponentByClass<UHexWidget>();
    Widget = Cast<UHexWidget>(this->FindComponentByClass<UHexWidget>());
    Widget = Cast<UHexWidget>(GetOwner()->FindComponentByClass<UHexWidget>());


}
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot work for multiple reasons :

1. `AHexCell` instance has no owner (it's an actor, it most likely has no owner, except if possessed by player controller).
2. `AHexCell` has no component `UHexWidget` and will likely never have : UHexWidget is a `UUserWidget` that class does not inherit `UActorComponent`
3. this is wrong because  1) and 2)

what you need to do (beside some OOP and Unreal Engine research) is :

```
class BATTLETECH_API AHexCell : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AHexCell();


    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category="Components")
    UWidgetComponent* widgetComp;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category="Grid Setup")
    UHexWidget* Widget;


protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

};


AHexCell::AHexCell()
{
   // spawn a widget component 
   widgetComp = createDefaultSubObject<UWidgetComponent>("widgetComponent");
   // or get it via FindComponent
   // widgetComp = FindComponentByClass<UWidgetComponent>();
}


AHexCell::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();
    // check if your pointer is valid before calling functions on it
    if(widgetComp != nullptr)
         Widget = Cast<UHexWidget>(widgetComp->GetUserWidgetObject());
}
```